# About the meaning of the term ''apparatus'' in this particular context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the word ''apparatus'' in this phrase:

''The introduction of a formal apparatus for inductive logic'' in this article: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-bayesian/

What does it mean in this context? What should I understand? Does it mean ''a formal system'' or literally ''formal equipment, tool''?

I have checked the dictionaries, of course, but I am not sure which meaning is compatible with this particular usage in the article. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please show your research. I'd suggest M-W 1c, with a broadened (abstract) sense for 'instrument' (Collins sense 4). And in fact, the Stanford article goes on to illustrate how the term is being used.

Comment: Are you thinking that an apparatus for logic could be a physical tool, like a machine?

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/apparatus) also has ***3** A collection of notes, variant readings, and other matter accompanying a printed text.*

Comment: Yosef Baskin, No, I do not think it is a physical tool. My question is not about the physical or abstract nature/meaning of the word. My question is about if the term means system or instrument which, in fact, both of them are already abstract.

Comment: Your link says "The formal apparatus itself has two main elements: the *use of the laws* of probability as coherence constraints on rational degrees of belief (or degrees of confidence) and the *introduction of a rule*."

Comment: For instance, there is a widely used ''tool'' in analytical philosophy called ''possible universes''. This is a mental tool to help philosophers create new ideas and thought experiments. In this regard, the tool is purely mental. In the same way, if apparatus in this context means an instrument or a tool, I understand that it'd be abstract.  But I do not think that is the problem that I am trying to find an answer to.

Comment: Emir, "apparatus" there means "process/procedure/algorithm/routine/method/anything like them…"

If you truly don't think it is a physical tool, why would you Question how the term might mean "instrument"? To me, for one, that sounds no more "abstract" than "tool"…

Comment: Robbie, as I mentioned above, ''possible universes'' in analytical philosophy, for instance, is a mental tool. So, formal apparatus can both mean a formal system or a formal tool. Both are possible, right? So, 'tool' option in my question does not have to refer to a physical tool.

Comment: My question is not ''If apparatus here means tool, then is it a physical or an abstract tool?''. My question is whether or not the phrase means tool (abstract) or system (again, abstract).

Answer (score 2):

An *apparatus* is a part of a [Formal System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system).

> A deductive system, also called a deductive apparatus or a logic, consists of the axioms (or axiom schemata) and rules of inference that can be used to derive theorems of the system.

Comment: Deductive or inductive?

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.